How to send SMS with Arabic and English words via Inetlab? Problem of word order
Good day! We send SMS messages via Inetlab. We faced with a problem when SMS contains mixed Arabic and English words. Arabic is right-to-left (RTL), but English is left-to-right (LTR). So mixed text with Arabic and English words is bidirectional.  When we send text via Inetlab, the words order changes.
Example, we want send this text:
%30 بالتخفيضات الصيفية لتصل إلى \u200eOurShopName تبدأ (I even can't copy-paste it here in proper order, so I added \u200e). We send without \u200e like in google doc: text with arabic and english words
But the word order is changing and we get SMS with this text:
تبدأ 12OurShopName بالتخفيضات الصيفية لتصل إلى 30٪
What we can do to solve this problem? Any ideas, we will appreciate it!
We send it in UCS-2 data coding.
Source AddressTon: Alphanumeric
Source AddressNpi: ISDN
DestinationTon: International
DestinationNpi: ISDN

The attached file with text contains the source text that should be sent (as a separate file, because StackOverFlow also changes the order of characters).
What have we already tried to do
We try to add \u200e symbol, but message contains \u200e symbol.
example from demo server and demo client.
When message doesn't contain % and OurShopName everything is great.
I read the Inetlab forum, but I didn't find a similar question. I also saw a question about flash SMS with Arabic - this is also not really our case.

The problem was on our side. Inetlab has nothing to do with it.
Problem that we try to send bidirectional text (bidi algorithm)
We solve this problem by adding LRM symbol when we want explicitly indicate that the following text should be written from left to right.
So text was:
%30 بالتخفيضات الصيفية لتصل إلى \u200e12OurShopName تبدأ
Become:
%30 بالتخفيضات الصيفية لتصل إلى ‎12OurShopName تبدأ (with U+200E symbol before 12OurShopName).
Thanks to Inetlab support (Alexey Tsynaev)
Test code
Unicode BiDi Algorithm:
The Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm is used to correctly display text containing both RTL and LTR scripts. This algorithm assigns directionality to each character and processes the text to determine the correct order for display.
Special characters, known as BiDi control characters, can be used to manage directionality. These include:
    LRM (Left-to-Right Mark): U+200E
    RLM (Right-to-Left Mark): U+200F
    LRE (Left-to-Right Embedding): U+202A
    RLE (Right-to-Left Embedding): U+202B
    PDF (Pop Directional Formatting): U+202C
    LRO (Left-to-Right Override): U+202D
    RLO (Right-to-Left Override): U+202E

